# Gitlab CI runner running python and numpy 1.18 from anaconda envirronment

Tags: numpy, python-3.7, gitlab-ci-runner, anaconda3

For gitlab ci jobs I have previously run test scripts via python like this

```
- c:\anaconda3\env\my_env\python test.py
```

With numpy 1.18, however, activating the envirronment is required, otherwise it fails to import

I have tried via conda run:

```
 - c:\anaconda3\scripts\conda run -n my_env -v python test.py
```

but then all output is swallowed (not shown in the job output).

I have also tried several ways and combinations of `activate` and `python test.py` with both cmd and powershell, but I have not found a way that activates the envirronment and runs the script with python from that envirronment.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using the git bash instead of powershell

- add `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to the system `PATH`-variable
- add to `c:\\[gitlab_runner_dir]/config.toml`

  ```
  shell = "bash"
  builds_dir="/c/gitlab-runner/builds/"
  cache_dir="/c/gitlab-runner/cache/"
  ```
- in `.gitlab-ci.yml` add:

  ```
  - source activate my_env
  ```